# Hide dynamic select after selecting a value jquery

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-core

I'm developing a project where there is an investigator and a sub-investigator, the question is that I wanted to disappear with the select in the second dropdown if it is selected with investigator, the problem is that the values ​​are dynamic.

[image: follow the image of the program and the dropdowns]

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Investigador Principal:<span class="red">*</span></label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        @Html.ListBoxFor( model => model.InvestigadorIdList,new MultiSelectList(Model.InvestigadorIdList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control select2 listas", id = "investigadorId",onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)" })
        <span asp-validation-for="InvestigadorIdList" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Sub Investigador:</label><br />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
        @Html.ListBoxFor( model => model.SubInvestigadoresListAux,new MultiSelectList(Model.SubInvestigadoresList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control listas", multiple = "multiple", id = "subinvestigadorId" ,onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)" })
        <span asp-validation-for="SubInvestigadoresListAux" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3">
        <label class="control-label">Coordenador:</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6" id="coordDiv">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.CoordenadoresListAux,new MultiSelectList(Model.CoordenadoresList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control listas", multiple = "multiple", id = "coordenadores",onchange="getSelectValue(this.value)" })
        <span asp-validation-for="CoordenadoresListAux" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my HTML selecting the list.

In jquery I'm lost, I made some attempts to block, but I can only block the field:

```js
function getSelectValue(investigadorId) {
    var teste = $('#investigadorId').find("selected").val();

    if (investigadorId != '') {
        $('#subinvestigadorId').prop('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

Someone to help?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove all options of sub selectlist when you select a item in main selectlist them add all items which were not selected in main selectlist to sub selectlist as below:

Models:

```
public class CompanyMember
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class GroupMember
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeViewModel
    {
        public SomeViewModel()
        {
            CompanyMemberList = new List<CompanyMember>();
            GroupMemberList = new List<GroupMember>();
        }
        public List<CompanyMember> CompanyMemberList { get; set; }
        public List<GroupMember> GroupMemberList { get; set; }
    }
```

controller:

```
public IActionResult MemberPage()
        {
            var vm = new SomeViewModel()
            {
                CompanyMemberList = new List<CompanyMember>()
                {
                    new CompanyMember(){Id=1,Name="jiang"},
                    new CompanyMember(){Id=2,Name="yang"},
                    new CompanyMember(){Id=3,Name="li"},
                    new CompanyMember(){Id=4,Name="wang"},
                    new CompanyMember(){Id=5,Name="zhang"}
                },
                GroupMemberList = new List<GroupMember>()
                {
                    new GroupMember(){Id=1,GroupId=1,Name="jiang"},
                    new GroupMember(){Id=3,GroupId=1,Name="li"},
                    new GroupMember(){Id=5,GroupId=1,Name="zhang"}
                }
            };
            return View(vm);
        }
```

View:

@model SomeViewModel

```
@{
    var companyselectlist = new SelectList(Model.CompanyMemberList, "Id", "Name");
    var groupselectlist = new SelectList(Model.GroupMemberList, "Id", "Name");
   
}
<select asp-for="CompanyMemberList" asp-items="companyselectlist" onchange="dynamicgroup()"></select>
<select asp-for=GroupMemberList asp-items="groupselectlist"></select>

<script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>    
    //get the array of value,text attr of sub selectlist
    function GetGroupList() {
        var grouparry = new Array();
        $('#GroupMemberList').children().each(function () {
            var obj = {}
            obj['v'] = $(this).val()
            obj['text'] = $(this).text()            
            grouparry.push(obj)
        });
        return grouparry;
    }
    
    
    var grouparr = GetGroupList();    

    function dynamicgroup()
    {
        //remove all options of sub selectlist
        $("#GroupMemberList option").remove()

        var somedic = grouparr
        // get the value attr of selected options of main selectlist
        var selectarr=new Array()
        $("#CompanyMemberList option:selected").each(function () {
            selectarr.push($(this).val())            
        })
        //add the option item to sub selectlist if not selected in main select list
        somedic.forEach((item, index, array) => {
            if (($.inArray(item.v, selectarr)) == -1)
            {
                $("#GroupMemberList").append(new Option(item.text, item.v, false, false))
            }            
        })
    }   
    
</script>
```

Result:

[image]